# Kotlin Gradle - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/konan/target/KonanTarget

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm using Kotlin Multiplatform with Gradle via Intellij, everything worked fine so far. I suddenly get an error when building the project

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/konan/target/KonanTarget

which didn't happen before. I remember deleting a few files from the Gradle cache recently, could it be because of that?

I thought I could run `gradle getDeps` and this would solve the problem, however this error occurs immediately on every Gradle task.

Comment: try deleting whole gradle cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleted whole `~/.gradle/caches` directory and reran `gradle build`. Now its working again - thanks to @Philip Dukhov